# function: sort output alphabetically

Tags: vimscript, functions, quickfix, sort

This function outputs data between braces as joined lines in a quickfix window. The output is sorted based on line numbers.

I'm searching for a method to sort the data alphabetically.

I tried to exclude `bufnr` and `lnum`, but that breaks the relocation to the actual buffer.

```
function! Overview() abort
    0
    let bufnr = bufnr('%')
    let items = []
    while 1
        let start = search('^{', 'cW')
        if !start
            break
        endif
        let end = search('^}', 'W')
        let lines = getline(start, end)
        let lines = map(lines, 'trim(v:val)')
        call add(items, {
            \ 'bufnr': bufnr,
            \ 'lnum': start,
            \ 'text': join(lines, ' '),
        \ })
    endwhile
    call setloclist(winnr(), items)
    lopen
endfunction
```

Comment: have you tried putting a `sort()` call after the `endwhile`?

Answer (score 1):

Include a call to `sort()` with a custom sorting function. This works for me based on your description:

```
" custom function that sorts the items by the 'text' key
function! Sorter(i1, i2) abort
 return a:i1['text'] == a:i2['text'] ? 0 : a:i1['text'] > a:i2['text'] ? 1 : -1
endfunction

function! Overview() abort
    0
    let bufnr = bufnr('%')
    let items = []
    while 1
        let start = search('^{', 'cW')
        if !start
            break
        endif
        let end = search('^}', 'W')
        let lines = getline(start, end)
        let lines = map(lines, 'trim(v:val)')
        call add(items, {
            \ 'bufnr': bufnr,
            \ 'lnum': start,
            \ 'text': join(lines, ' '),
        \ })
    endwhile
    " sort using the Sorter function to compare items
    call sort(items, 'Sorter')
    call setloclist(winnr(), items)
    lopen
endfunction
```

See also `:help sort()` for more information.