# substitute lines in a function

Tags: substitute

In this function I would like to substitute everything within `("` and `")` with emptiness

```
function! ListJoinFolds() abort
    0
    let bufnr = bufnr('%')
    let items = []
    while 1
        let start = search('^{{{', 'cW')
        if !start
            break
        endif
        let end = search('^}}}', 'W')
        let lines = getline(start, end)
        let lines = map(lines, 'trim(v:val)')
        call add(items, {
            \ 'bufnr': bufnr,
            \ 'lnum': start,
            \ 'text': join(lines, ' '),
        \ })
        " credits to: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/akv0wl/function_sort_output_alphabetically/ef8nlrr
        call sort(items, {a, b -> a["text"] == b["text"] ? 0 : a["text"] > b["text"] ? 1 : -1})
    endwhile
    call setloclist(winnr(), items)
    lopen
endfunction
```

I've added the following nearly every thinkable order I could think of, but my intelligence couldn't find the right place to succeed for the attempted success.

```
let lines = substitute(items, '(".\{-}")', '', 'g')
```

Hopefully someone could assist me with this.

Thank you.

PS

I've also posted this question to:

reddit.com/r/vim ([link](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/aomufd/substitute_lines_in_a_function/))

If question solved, I will post it here, and vice versa.

Comment: You might want to update https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18733/function-sort-output-alphabetically now that you've solved that problem.

Comment: Braces can be embedded. Even with a correct syntax, we can have things like `f(g(), h(y()))`.. And unfortunately, regexes are really bad with recursive patterns. `searchpair()` could have helped, but it works on buffers, not on strings. May be there is a Python library somewhere that can help, in that case it may be better to delegate your problem to that library from your vim function.

Answer (score 1):

`substitute()` only works on a *string*. You appear to have been trying it with the `items` list. Does something like this work for you (as a modification of the part where you add the text to the items list)?

```
    call add(items, {
        \ 'bufnr': bufnr,
        \ 'lnum': start,
        \ 'text': substitute(join(lines, ' '), '(".\{-}")', '', 'g'),
    \ })
```